# Show EditText data as suggestion in android

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

[image]Hello,

I have a requirement to use MultiAutoCompleteTextView and I implemented that. But suppose if there is no suggestion in the list then the data(word) whatever the user entered should be displayed as like suggestion.

For Example: String[] a = new String["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]{};
Suppose this is the String array and assigning to EditText when there is matching data like"a".

But if I want to display the data that is not present in adapter then that data or word will display the text as shown in suggestion list.

Please help me.

I have also without image posted the same question at [Show EditText data as suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761779/show-edittext-data-as-suggestion/34762465#34762465)

Comment: You need to show suggestions from history that user has already typed right?

Comment: No, I want to show like suggestion if user is typing even for the first time.

Comment: In the image above I was typing for the first time and it is displaying as it. In the same way I want to do this. Can you suggest me how can I do that??